# Python подключение модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x

При импорте модуля почему-то используется его старая версия, которую я уже переписал. Судя по всему она закэшировалась. Почему так и как это исправить? 
Пример: `import bstvis.tree.tango_strict as tg`

Comment: Пример можете привести?

Comment: @Александр, Сложно придумать пример. У меня есть, например, класс бинарного дерева поиска, реализованный в отдельном файле, который лежит в папке tree. И есть файл визуализирующий это дерево, который лежит в другой папке view. Обе эти папки лежат в основной папке bstree. И вот при обращении из файла визуализации к файлу дерева, применяется устаревшая версия этого класса.

Comment: 1. Добавьте в вопрос хотя бы строчку импорта, без неё совсем беспредметный разговор получается. 2. Если открыть файл в tree обычным тестовым редактором, то вы видите там новые изменения? 3. Есть ли в папке tree файлы с расширением *.pyc? Если есть, попробуйте их удалить. 4. Как вы запускаете файл с визуализацией? Из консоли или как-то ещё?

Comment: @Александр, Да изменения я вижу, есть в папке tree папка _pycache_ и в ней файлы *.pyc. Я пытался ее удалить первым делом, но при запуске она создается заново. Запускаю через консоль

Comment: Сразу после строки с импортом добавьте: print(tg.__file__)  Проверьте, что вывелось - соответствует ли путь той папке, откуда должен происходить импорт.

Comment: Да в этом и была проблема, спасибо, исправлю